# Multiple tasks are not running

Tags: discord.py

Currently this is the code. When I am running two tasks at a time, Only 1 is executed. Another one is not running. Any possible reasons or solutions?

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Server Started')
    await ev_1.start()
    await ev_2.start()

@tasks.loop(minutes = 1)
async def ev_1():
    print('passed1')

@tasks.loop(minutes = 2)
async def ev_2():
    print('passed2')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Loop.start` is not a coroutine, when awaiting it you're waiting till the function finishes. Fixed code:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Server Started')
    ev_1.start()
    ev_2.start()
```

Comment: When would you use await to start a loop?

Comment: @Tatsuya If you want to wait for the loop to finish, `Loop.start` returns a [`asyncio.Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task) which you can await.